# Android development with C++ and SDL2

Tags: java, android, c++, sdl-2

I have an Application based heavily based on SLD2, and I would like to port it on Android(Its currently available for Windows, Linux, MacOS and iOS).
After doing a lot of research the cleanest way I have found was to use the Android Native activity and start my C++ code from there. That worked great, my next step was to build SDL2 as a dynamic library and included in the project which also worked fine. Although when I tried to Initialise SDL video, sound etc. I found out that SDL2 can only be Initialised inside the SDL_Activity provided by the SDL source code.

Is that true?

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do?

My code base is quiet big and replacing the main class that takes care of the SDL rendering, with a java class will affect a lot of my base code.

Is there an other alternative or a guide to get inspiration?

Comment: There is an `android-project` directory in SDL source archive. It contains `SDLActivity` with bridging code. Mostly you just continue with `main` function, SDL will redefine it to `SDL_main` and call it from this java file, which in many cases you'll never need to touch.

Comment: @keltar Is the SDLActivity just an adaptor class or I have to make all the SDL calls from there?

Comment: You just write your ordinary C/C++ code startning with `main` (which `SDL.h` will redefine to `SDL_main`). `SDLActivity` will pass execution to your code (it also processes events so you'll get them via ordinary `SDL_PollEvent`, etc.). Basicaly if you aren't douing something very tricky you'll never need to write java code at all.

Comment: @keltar Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry for the all the questions but I am not really experienced with the android ecosystem. I have tried open the android-project on Android studio but that just doesn't work. Its missing the gradle and I don't fully understand how to make it work. Should I try it on eclipse? Is there an other alternative?  what is your suggestion?(btw I am working an a Mac). Again sorry for all the extra questions.

Comment: Don't really know, it's been quite a time now, and I never used an IDE. I've used `ant` to build apk and custom makefile to build `.so` (you might want to use `ndk-build` here, as it may be simplier and SDL doc covers that). Makefile here is incomplete as it have reference to `YourSourceHere.c`, which obviously needs to be replaced by something more meaningful. There is also `docs/README-android.md` file in SDL that describes how it should be used.

Comment: @keltar Thanks again for the help! I am going to look into what you've suggested!

Comment: @keltar So I did try the SDLActivity but I don't seam to be able to debug the  created a gradle based project so I can run it on Android studio. But it won't debug. Any clue?

Comment: Sorry, as I've said before - no IDEs for me, so I can't help you as I have no idea what debugging facilities IDE uses. If it does have support for native code debugging, then it is very likely to be remote gdb - which needs to be installed on target device; take a look at e.g. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/wiki/Android-debugging-with-remote-GDB but once again - I haven't done any android programming for years, things might have changed.